# Error when trying to set up firebase with react native 0.63

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am new to react native and firebase and am trying to create an app that uses firebase to send background notifications within iOS.

When I run my app I seem to get the following error message and my app won't run.

> TypeError: (0, _app2.messaging) is not a function. (In '(0, _app2.messaging)()', '(0, _app2.messaging)' is undefined)

Here is my firebase code.

```js
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

import {messaging} from '@react-native-firebase/app';

requestUserPermission = async () => {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
  }
};

  // Register background handler
   messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
   console.log('Messaage handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
 });

 HeadlessCheck = ({ isHeadless }) => {
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has beeen launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }
  return <App />;
 }

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);
```

I might be writing my firebase code wrong as I am new to firebase and I'm still unsure what I am doing and am simply trying to follow a few online tutorials.

I did google this problem but not one seems to be having it. I tried to delete my node_modules folder and ran yarn again but this didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that messaging does not exist, I noticed you are importing messaging from `@react-native-firebase/app`. Following the docs (https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage) looks like you need a different module.

Installing the messaging module:

```sh
# Install the messaging module
yarn add @react-native-firebase/messaging

# If you're developing your app using iOS, run this command
cd ios/ && pod install
```

Importing `messaging` for usage

```js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I didn't pick up on this.